# Drupal 7, Entity Reference user autocomplete field

Tags: ajax, entities

I have a custom content type that has a users: entity reference autocomplete field. For some reason the list gets populated as [realname] ([name]). In other words the realname and username tokens are both shown in the autocomplete list. Is there a way to only show the realname token?

I would like to go from this...
[image: Current Entity Reference as Autocomplete field]

To this
[image: Desired Entity Reference as Autocomplete field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a view for the autocomplete.

You can use this tutorial: http://speaksdrupal.com/blog/custom-entityreference-handlers-using-views

Then add that as the view to use for autocomplete.

http://screencast.com/t/8m0O7F8zV

Whatever fields are searched will show up in the drop down.  So if you remove e-mail from the list of fields searched, it won't show up in the drop-down.

Comment: thanks!! worked great... just have to remember to change the view's default access permissions otherwise it seems to not change the rendered entity reference for anonymous users!!